# Python: Workaround for NoneType in ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree, attributeerror, nonetype

Good day to all of you,

I'm trying to load an .xml-file with ElementTree with the following code:

```
data = []
    root = et.fromstring(r.content)
    user = root.findall('.//user')
    for u in user:
        data.append(
            {'id': u.get('id'),
             'firstName': u.find('firstName').text,
             'lastName': u.find('lastName').text,
             'personnelNumber': u.find('personnelNumber').text}
             )
```

I know that there are a few - maybe half a dozen - rows where 'personnelNumber' is empty, so I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I would like to ask if someone knows a workaround for this problem? I honestly don't care about the few missing entrys, so that I only achieve the rest!?

Thanks for all your help and a great weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unconditionally access properties on something that might be `None`.

The result of `u.find('xyz')` will be `None` when there is no child node named `xyz` in `u`, so `u.find('xyz').text` can fail.

Use a helper function.

```
def get_text(elem, fallback_value=None):
    return elem.text if elem else fallback_value

data = []
root = et.fromstring(r.content)
for u in root.findall('.//user'):
    data.append({
        'id': u.get('id'),
        'firstName': get_text(u.find('firstName')),
        'lastName': get_text(u.find('lastName')),
        'personnelNumber': get_text(u.find('personnelNumber'))
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for this late response!

Comment: No worries @finethen!